# issue with console.readline(); in c# whatever number i input it chnages it to the number 49

Tags: c#

I am completely new to c# and this is my first program.

```
 namespace CPU_load {
    class Program {

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Jackson CPU monitor");
            Console.WriteLine("Press ESC at any time to exit");
            //instructions_1 = Console.WriteLine("Would you like the view the instructions (y/n)   ");
            Console.Write("How often would you like to take a reading?(in seconds)    ");
            interval = Console.Read();

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(interval);

            interval_int1 = Convert.ToInt32(interval);
            //int interval_int = (int)interval;
            int interval_int_milliseconds = interval_int * 1000;

            Console.WriteLine("A reading will be taken every {0} seconds", interval_int1);

            Thread.Sleep(2500);
            PerformanceCounter perfCPUcount = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
            PerformanceCounter perfMEMcount = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
            ConsoleColor oldColor = Console.ForegroundColor;

            while (true) {
                float cpuload = (int) perfCPUcount.NextValue();
                float memload = (int) perfMEMcount.NextValue();

                if (cpuload == 100) {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                }


                if (cpuload <= 20) {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                }

                Console.Write("CPU load {0}%                           ", cpuload);
                Console.ForegroundColor = oldColor;
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                Console.WriteLine(now);
                Console.ForegroundColor = oldColor;

                if (memload <= 500) {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                }

                if (memload <= 1500) {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                }


                if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) break;

                Console.WriteLine("Available Memory {0}MB", memload);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Console.ForegroundColor = oldColor;
        }

        public static int interval_int {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public static int interval {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public static int interval_int1 {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
 }
```

no matter what number I input I always get the number `49` ouputted on line 6 of the code above. I dont know why it is happening it is a cpu usage monitor and I want to use the users input as the delay between reading cpu usage.

Comment: where can i paste it?

Comment: The same place you put the code in your question...

Comment: In your question [by editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30676623/edit)

Comment: Or just paste it on pastebin or something and we can edit it for you...

Comment: Please try to provide *small* sample. It is very unlikely all this code is required to demonstrate problem.

Comment: Side note: based on code you've provided "no matter what number I input I always get the number 49" can't be true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing `Console.Read();` which only reads a single character and returns its ASCII value.

The reason it outputs 49 is because 49 is the ASCII value for `1`.

You need to use `Console.ReadLine()` to get the text entered then use something like `int.TryParse` to convert the text in to the number representation.